# Monodroid - ImageView -> SetImageURI crash application

Tags: android, mono, crash, imageview

I have an issue displaying a picture taken from the Camera.
I proceed as the following:

1. Calling Camera Activity -> Saving Picture -> Keeping Picture Location as a string.
2. Creating a new Intent -> Setting String extra with the Picture Location.
3. Calling the activity and retreiving the string.
4. Switching back to an URI using Parse on the string containing the file location.
5. Calling SetImageURI on the ImageView. <- this crashes.

I get the "Application had to close unexpectedly" thing..

Not really handy to debug.

There's the code for the Activity:

```
    [Activity (Label = "ViewPhoto")]            
public class ViewPhoto : Activity
{
    ImageView image;
    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        string PhotoLocation = Intent.GetStringExtra ("PicLoc");
        Android.Net.Uri _img = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (PhotoLocation);
        image.SetImageURI (_img);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PhotoViewer);
        image = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.exCurrentPhoto);
    }
}
```

I checked the picture weight.. it's 9kb (its probably a simple picture generated through the android emulator I use).. so I doubt it's a memory issue o.o

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate myself for not noticing I had forgotten to call the base.OnResume() function...
Without exception being thrown I didn't realise until I randomly had to go through the Android LogCat x)

Problem solved =D